# Model State Always true even when the required field is not sent

Tags: json, api, validation, .net-core, modelstate

I am simply calling an API and passing an object as a parameter and everything works fine. But then i wanted to validate the model before going any further so i simply wrote [Required] above the fields i always wanted filled.
MODEL

```
public class Consent
{
    public Consent()
    {
       
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int FacilityId { get; set; }
    public string Heading { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

and validate the model state in controller like this

```
public ActionResult<int> AddConsent(Consent consent)
{
    if(!ModelState.IsValid){
        throw new CustomException("000-0000-000", "Validation failed");
        
    }
    //Further Code
}
```

By this i expected model state to be false when i don't send the facilityId when i call the api
JSON

```
{
    "heading": "HeadingFromPostman5",
    "description": "DiscriptiomFromPostman5"
}
```

but its still true . I know .Net core is allocating 0 to int value when null but how can i validate it then? Whats the work around for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply replace this line:

```
[Required]
public int FacilityId { get; set; }
```

With this:

```
[Required]
public int? FacilityId { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

The Required attribute works well for nullable reference objects. For primitives, when an instance is created, the default value (in this case 0 for int) is assigned for FacilityId, and hence the Required won't work. If you make the FacilityId as nullable int then the Required attribute will work fine.

```
[Required]
public int? FacilityId { get; set; }
```